# Google Cloud Messaging payload with application data using Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to send notification from my backend application to Android mobile phones. I managed to install devices and remove them. Now I have problems with the message payload. I need sound alert, and I need to send some application data in the message. This is how I build the payload now, but I think it's not good:

```
string notificationText = NotificationText(story, profile);

JProperty messageJProperty = new JProperty("message", notificationText);
JObject messageJObject = new JObject(messageJProperty);
JProperty objectJProperty = new JProperty("data", messageJObject);
JObject message = new JObject(objectJProperty);
var payload = message.ToString();

return payload;
```

thnx

update (2017-nov-3):
I found that this payload format will be accepted by Azure:

```
private string Payload(string notificationText, StoryEntity story, ProfileEntity profile, string deviceToken)
{
        var payload = new JObject
        (
            new JProperty("registration_ids", new JArray(deviceToken)),
            new JProperty("data", new JObject(
                                              new JProperty("title", "Mapporia has new stroy>"),
                                              new JProperty("message", notificationText)
                                              )),
            new JProperty("notId", $"{new Random().Next(int.MaxValue)}"),
            new JProperty("content-available", 1),
            new JProperty("soundname", "default"),
            new JProperty("image", @"www/assets/img/logo.png"),
            new JProperty("image-type", "circle"),
            new JProperty("style", "inbox"),
            new JProperty("notData", new JObject(
                                                   new JProperty("storyId", story.Id),
                                                   new JProperty("profileId", profile.Id)
                                                 ))
        ).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

        return payload;
    }
```

This is how my json looks like:

[image]

But now Azure is throwing an exception:

> 1 2017-11-01 Create Story : The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request. The supplied notification payload is
>   invalid.TrackingId:666febf6-85fe-4ebd-867d-00ce5a668809_G3,TimeStamp:11/1/2017
>   9:53:07 PM

Did I miss something?
According to this [page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options), I built it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

The correct JSON format for GCM is:

```
    {
        "to" : "{{devicetoken}} OR {{registrationID form Azure}}",
        "data":
            {
                "title":"{{title goes here}}",
                "message":"{{message body goes here}}",
                "priority":"high"
            },
        "notId":"{{unique ID, I used RANDOM to generate it}}",
        "content-available":1,
        "soundname":"default",
        "image":"www/assets/img/logo.png",
        "image-type":"circle",
        "style":"inbox",
        "notData":
            {
                "storyId":1,
                "profileId":6
            }
    }
```

And how to build this JSON using c# with Newtonsoft JSON nuget packege:

```
            var payload = new JObject
            (
                new JProperty("to", deviceToken),
                new JProperty("data", new JObject(
                                                  new JProperty("title", "title goes here"),
                                                  new JProperty("message", "notification text goes here"),
                                                  new JProperty("priority", "high")
                                                  )),
                new JProperty("notId", $"{new Random().Next(int.MaxValue)}"),
                new JProperty("content-available", 1),
                new JProperty("soundname", "default"),
                new JProperty("image", @"www/assets/img/logo.png"),
                new JProperty("image-type", "circle"),
                new JProperty("style", "inbox"),
                new JProperty("notData", new JObject(
                                                       new JProperty("storyId", story.Id),
                                                       new JProperty("profileId", profile.Id)
                                                     ))
            ).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is how I build the payload now, but I think it's not good

If understanding correctly and if the struction of the json is fixed, we could serialize object to do that. The following is the demo code:

```
string notificationText = NotificationText(story, profile);

TestData testData = new TestData { Data = new Data { Message = notificationText }};
        
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData).ToLowerInvariant();


 public class TestData
 {
       public Data Data;
 }

 public class Data
 {
      public string Message;
 }
```

**Updated:**

A GCM message can be up to 4kb of payload to the client app, we could get more info about GCM message from this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).The limitation is 4kb and cannot be any larger. If you need to send a sound, my suggestion is that to send custom json with the message that points to a URL that houses the binary data.

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers to send messages between servers and client apps. This includes downstream messages from servers to client apps, and upstream messages from client apps to servers.
>
> For example, a lightweight downstream message could inform a client app that there is new data to be fetched from the server, as in the case of a "new email" notification. For use cases such as instant messaging, a GCM message can **transfer up to 4kb** of payload to the client app. The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to and from the target client app.

Comment: The payload format is the problem, not how to build it physically.

Comment: I have updated the  answer.  More detail info please refer to the **Updated** section.

Comment: Thnx, I got this part how. I want to know how to send app data within notification, how to enable sound.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your payload to this call

```
 var payload = new JObject(
                      new JProperty("data", new JObject(
                      new JProperty("message", notificationText))))
                      .ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

The output will be the JSON formatted payload as GCM accepts it.

```
{"data":{"message":"your notification Text"}}
```

In this solution I have used the Newtonsoft's JSON serializer to serialize my JObject.